# regexp to put one var into the value of regexp of another

Tags: c#

How to put my var userId to regexp?

```
string userId = "ololoawd";

string did = Regex.Match(content, @"""dID"":""(.*?)"",""dOF"":true,""dOID"":"" + userId + "",""usS"":").Groups[1].Value;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You didn't specify what you were expecting as an output.  All I can see is that you didn't terminate your first string properly before concatenating the userId in.  Try the following:

```
string userId = "ololoawd";
string did = Regex.Match(content, @"""dID"":""(.*?)"",""dOF"":true,""dOID"":""" + userId + @""",""usS"":").Groups[1].Value;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
string did = Regex.Match(content, @"""dID"":""(.*?)"",""dOF"":true,""dOID"":" + userId + ",""usS"":").Groups[1].Value;
```